# node-openid-client, how to resolve errors like "callbackParams of undefined" and "state mismatch"

Tags: openid-connect, openid-client-js

Regarding this library https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client

Is that correct to assume that the same openIdClient instance should be handling both openIdClient.authorizationUrl() and openIdClient.callbackParams() for a particular authentication request.

As I found out, it could be wrong, that if the instance is different between these 2 calls, then "callbackParams of undefined" and "state mismatch" errors could happen, especially in a multi-instance environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the client should be the same instance that handles the initial authentication request and that also retrieves the final tokens from the OICD provider.

Most of the security features like state and PKCE in OICD requires this to be true.

Comment: Thanks @Tore Nestenius for confirming this.

My next question is how could I ensure this behaviour in Node.js, especially there could be multiple API service instances behind load balancer / API gateway (for callback)?

Comment: In my case the architecture is: web app - api service - idp, should I attach the openid client to the request / response session over the course?

Comment: Either you handle that in the load balancer to tie a specific user to a given instance, perhaps based on a cookie value? Also you have to be careful about HTTPS/HTTP and where you terminate HTTPS, as typically you have HTTP on the inside ant HTTPS on the outside, and that can give you some nice headaches as well.

Comment: alternatively you could give each service instance an name like client1.myservice.com, client2.myservice.com... and use that in the redirect URI to make sure the user is redirected back to the same instance after authentication.

Comment: All of the above is incorrect and misleading. There is no requirement for the same Instance of the Client class to handle the init and callback phases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for the same Instance of the Client class to handle the init and callback phases.

Not being able to access `Client.prototype.callbackParams` due to `client` being `undefined` is an application level error.

The OP's problem in question is being handled in a package that includes `openid-client` [here](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/pull/545).

Comment: Yes you are right, I've raised PR to fix the application level library
https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/pull/545